# How do I post variables from Flash Builder 4.6 and get the result in PHP? Any Ideas?

Tags: php, sql, post, flash-builder

I'm rather new to Flash Builder but I've read some articles on the web and on here and it's a persistent problem that I just can't seem to solve.

In Flash Builder, I have a search bar with an ID of 'searchBar'. Along with the search bar there's a button labelled 'Submit'.

How my system works is this:

1. I have set up a HTTP Service:

   ```
     <s:HTTPService id="searchBookAuthor"
                  url="http://localhost/cm0665-assignment/web/libraryServicePipe.php"
                  result="searchBookAuthor_resultHandler(event)"
                  fault="libraryService_faultHandler(event)"
                  method="POST"
                  >

       <s:request xmlns="">
           <searchBar>{searchBar.text}</searchBar>
       </s:request>

   </s:HTTPService>
   ```
2. User enters a search term in the search box and clicks 'Submit'
3. When the button is clicked, a click_handler event is called, and within here I have made a variable:

   ```
    var param:Object = new Object;
               param.action = 'search';
               searchBookAuthor.send(param); // ID of HTTPService
   ```

3. The action = 'search' relates to a case function in my PHP server side file.

My problem is that I dont know how to get the data that the user enters to be picked up in PHP. I have this but it doesn't work (though I've tested the script by passing the URL some parameters):

```
$searchValue = $_POST["searchBar"];

                $recset = new T_XMLRecordSet();

                $searchSQL = "select Title, Author from l_stock WHERE Title OR Author LIKE '%$searchValue%'";

                $result = $recset ->getRecordSet($searchSQL, 'book');
                return $result;
```

And the result returns every Title and Author in my database and $_POST['searchBar'] doesn't seem to getting the data. Sorry it's a lot to look at it but I really don't know where I'm going wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit a little bit your request structure:

```
<s:request xmlns="">
    <searchBar>{searchBar.text}</searchBar>
    <action>search</action>
</s:request>
```

then in click_handler event:

```
searchBookAuthor.send()
```

This should work.

*When you are passing `param` to `send()` function, you are basically overwriting your request structure. In other word, you can also do it in this way:

```
var param:Object = new Object;
            param.action = 'search';
            param.searchBar = searchBar.text;
            searchBookAuthor.send(param);
```